# How is change in enthalpy in a cyclic process zero when work done is not equal to zero and the change in internal energy is equal to zero

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, work

We know that change in internal energy is equal to heat supplied - work done in a cyclic process. The change in internal energy is zero and work done is non-zero. This implies that the heat given is non zero then how can the enthalpy change be 0?

Comment: Enthalpy is a state variable, so it’s net change during a cycle must be zero. I suspect you are mixing this up with the fact that during an isobaric process, change in enthalpy is equal to heat, but that is *only* for an isobaric process.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 2):

Internal  energy, pressure and volume are all state properties. A cycle returns all properties to their original values. So the change in each of these is zero. Enthalpy is defined as

$$H=U+PV$$

Therefore it too is a state property so its change is also zero.

Work and heat are energy transfers and are not properties. They depend on the processes carried out during the cycle. since $\Delta U=0$ then $W=Q$. Meaning the net work done in a cycle  equals the net heat added.

> This implies that the heat given is non zero then how can the enthalpy
> change be 0?

Enthalpy is defined as above. It only equals the heat transferred for a  constant pressure *process*, as follows.

$$\Delta H=\Delta U+\Delta (PV)$$
$$\Delta H=Q-W+P\Delta V+V\Delta P$$

For a constant pressure process, $W=P\Delta V$ and $V\Delta P=0$, and therefore

$$\Delta H=Q=mC_{p}\Delta T$$

And $\Delta H$ is positive if heat is added to the system resulting in a temperature increase. *But a process does not constitute a cycle.* For a cycle the temperature must return to its original value. This require us to reverse the constant pressure process to transfer the same amount of heat out of the system making $\Delta H=0$ for the cycle.

Hope this helps